# Need support about connecting to a database mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, passwords

I'm using a .php file that creates connection to a mysql database. But after filling the needed info, the webpage shows the following error

> Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I'm also trying to create a db and a user with mysql console via ssh (I'm using linux-plesk panel) but nothing changed. I'm using another kind of that scripts too but I dont know whats wrong with that one. I will paste the codes here:

```
<? 
mysql_connect ("localhost","dbuser","dbpass");
mysql_select_db("db");
?>
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that no password is being presented to the mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
$connect = mysql_connect('host', 'mysql-user', 'mysql-pass');
if (!$connect) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("mysql-database", $connect);
```

It's pretty much the same but I'm using it on my server and it's working so it should work in your case as well. As Mitch suggested your script is trying to login to the mysql database using an empty user so that's the reason you get that error.

Also you could try from the shell prompt to check if the mysql credentils are actually working:

```
$ mysql -h mysql-host -u mysql-username -p mysql-database
```

Enter the mysql password and see if you are connected or not